# How do I write an SQL query where two columns need to be translated?

Tags: mysql, join

I've got two tables- one with records of stock, the other with translations (for French and German users).

Stock:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ PRICE ║ ITEMTRANSLATIONID ║ ITEMCATEGORYTRANSLATIONID ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║    10 ║               423 ║                      1323 ║
║  2 ║    31 ║              1776 ║                      1953 ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════════════════╝
```

Translations:

```
╔══════╦═══════════╦════════════╦═════════╗
║  ID  ║  ENGLISH  ║   FRENCH   ║ GERMAN  ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║    1 ║ knife     ║ couteau    ║ messer  ║
║    2 ║ fork      ║ fourchette ║ gabel   ║
║  423 ║ spoon     ║ cuillère   ║ löffel  ║
║ 1323 ║ cultery   ║ couverts   ║ besteck ║
║ 1776 ║ table     ║ table      ║ tabelle ║
║ 1953 ║ furniture ║ meubles    ║ möbel   ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

Is there a way to write an SQL query to get prices and translated names for each stock item? I will only ever need one language at once.

If only one column needed translating, I could just use an `INNER JOIN`. The trouble is, there are two columns that need translating- one for the item name, the other for the item category name.

i.e. 
Required Output (French)

```
╔════╦═══════╦══════════╦══════════════╗
║ ID ║ PRICE ║   ITEM   ║ ITEMCATEGORY ║
╠════╬═══════╬══════════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║    10 ║ cuillère ║ couverts     ║
║  2 ║    31 ║ table    ║ meubles      ║
╚════╩═══════╩══════════╩══════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

join table `Translations` twice on table `Stock` so you could get the values for each columns in table `Stock`

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Price, b.French AS Item, c.French AS ItemCategory  
FROM    Stock a
        INNER JOIN Translations b
            ON a.ItemTranslationId = b.ID
        INNER JOIN Translations c
            ON a.ItemCategoryTranslationId = c.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fba2/1)

Comment: Thank you. (I've struggled for hours- Three minutes on Stackoverflow and I'm sorted.)

Comment: by the way, if there has chances that either of them can be null, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

With this table structure, you would need to `JOIN` to the `Translations` table twice... once to get the `Item`, and again to get the `ItemCategory`:

```
SELECT
    s.ID,
    s.Price,
    i.French AS Item,
    ic.French AS ItemCategory
FROM
    Stock s
    JOIN Translations i ON i.ID = s.ItemTranslationId
    JOIN Translations ic ON ic.ID = s.ItemCategoryTranslationId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Price,
(select French from  Translations b where b.ID=a.ItemTranslationId) as ITEM,
(select French from  Translations c where c.ID=a.ItemCategoryTranslationId) as ITEMCATEGORY
FROM Stock a
```